# Can't always access my Raspberry Pi through PuTTY

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and started to set it up. I followed some tutorials and finally was able to access it remotely without having to plug it to a monitor, a keyboard, a mouse...

Everything is okay but it just bothers me a little bit that whenever I reboot it or I don't use it for some time I have to ping it on the computer before being able to control it remotely. If I don't ping it, connection fails.

It's not a big problem but is something I'd like to be solved. Thank you for your attention!

UPDATE: Just did a clean installation and now it works fine and can be accessed remotely at any time. Thanks to anybody that tried to help!

Comment: Maybe it is in sleep mode.

Comment: I thought the Raspberry Pi didnt't have "sleep" mode. If it has, how do I disable it?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=144833

Comment: Just got it working properly by doing a clean installation, thanks guys.